# RoR, resque, JSON::GeneratorError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I use Rails 4.1.6
I try started resque worker but I get error:

```
JSON::GeneratorError in BookRelationsController#import_books
partial character in source, but hit end
```

My code:

```
file = 'public/file.xlsx'
Resque.enqueue(ProcessImportJob, File.new(file))
```

How fix this error?
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `File` object as an argument to `Resque`. You can pass only those arguments, that can be parsed to `JSON`

`Resque.enqueue(ProcessImportJob, 'public/file.xlsx')`

Then in your worker process you open the file using the passed filename.

Comment: There's no way around it. The arguments are stored in `redis` and respresented as `json`, you woun't be able to pass `File` object.